# List of unanswered questions

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

Hi,

Why does [this question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/how-can-i-attach-more-text-to-a-tfs-task-with-msproject) appear to be unanswered, as it is, obviously, answered? The answered was added for 4 days, so it can hardly be a latency problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A question is considered answered:

- When person who has originally asked the question, marks one answer as `accepted answer`, or;
- When one answer has at least **one** up-vote from *someone*.

The question you mentioned appear as unanswered because the answer don't have any up-vote.

Comment: we consider a question unanswered until at least one answer has one upvote from *someone*

Answer (score 1):

Just because a question has an answer doesn't mean it has been **answered**.  The question you cite is a great example.  The OP is asking how to pull in the Description field from TFS into MS Project.  The answerer suggests using TFS Web Access instead, which, while a so-so suggestion, does not answer the question.  At least, that's why I didn't upvote that particular answer :)